# How to make emacs allow opening one buffer in different frames?

Tags: emacs

I have two frames of the same Emacs instance (got them by `C-x 5 2`) and a file opened in one of these frames. Then I try to show this file in a buffer in another frame (by `C-x b`) and nothing happens.

Actually, I think it shows this file in a buffer in the first frame, but this is not what I want it to do. I want it to show this buffer in both frames.

When there is only one frame and some windows in it, opening one buffer in different windows is no problem. I want the same behaviour but with several frames.

Comment: Assuming that you want Buffer A to display in Frame Number 2, I have the following questions:  If you are in Frame Number 1 looking at Buffer A, do you want to switch focus to Frame Number 2 with focus on Buffer A?  Or, would you prefer that focus remain in Frame Number 1 with focus on Buffer A?  Also, am I assuming correctly that you begin with focus on Buffer A in Frame Number 1; or do you initially have focus on another buffer in Frame Number 1 (e.g., Buffer B, C, D, etc.)?  Did you already try `switch-to-buffer-other-frame`; and, if so, how does that behavior differ from your goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you are using iswitch, as what you describe is its default behavior.

You can change it by doing `M-x customize-variable RET iswitchb-default-method`.  probably you want to choose option `samewindow`

The ido equivalent variable , in case you are using it, is `ido-default-buffer-method` (ido defaults to `raise-frame`, that does not match with your observed behavior).

You may find if you are using one or the other using the way @Olaf describes.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly my issue. I use `ido`, and after I changed `ido-default-buffer-method` to `Show in selected window` instead of `Raise frame if already shown` all works as I want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you have <kbd>C-x b</kbd> redefined. I have the same behaviour with `iswitch-buffer`. But when I enter <kbd>M-x switch-to-buffer</kbd>, it shows the buffer in the second window.

You can find out, which command is executed with <kbd>C-h c C-x b</kbd>.